# Asus P8Z68-V LX UEFI BIOS

Tags: resolution, uefi

I have a had a custom built PC for about 6 months.  I'm using an old Dell monitor which can support 1280x1024 but I prefer to keep the resolution at 1024x768  as its easier for me to read.

My problem is my motherboard has Asus's UEFI firmware.  When entering the EUFI program I can only see the top left corner of the page and that fills the entire screen and everything is HUGE! it looks a little pixelated but not very much. here is a screen shot below. My Question is if there is a fix to this or if anyone else is experiencing this?

Picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBEyk.jpg

Comment: Really the only solution I have found is if you are using DVI try VGA and vice versa.

Comment: i am using a VGA but HDMI works fine on my TV.

Comment: Does your monitor support any other cables? If so, I advise you to try those.

Comment: it only supports VGA and the VGA is directly connected to the inside.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this problem before with a gigabyte board, except that problem was a lot worse. The thing that went wrong here is your cable connection. What ever cable your using is causing the problem. You need to switch it for a more modern one.